# Why is v-for not working in this VueJS todo app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an extension that has an advanced todo app, The user add todo tasks, those tasks will be saved on localStorage, when the extension has a certain state (called "work") , it shows those tasks stored in the localStorage .

Tasks are added per session, so each session, has a list of tasks, I keep an index of the current session, to show the tasks of that session when the state is to work .

Here's the code responsible for this .

```
    todoManager = new Vue({
  el: "#todoEl",
  data: {
    tasks: JSON.parse(localStorage["pr_sessions"])[JSON.parse(localStorage["pr_currSession"]) - 1].tasks,
    numOfTasks: JSON.parse(localStorage["pr_sessions"])[JSON.parse(localStorage["pr_currSession"]) - 1].tasks.length
  },
  methods:{
    checkTask: function(){
      // Do Something cool here
    }
  }

})
```

My HTML template :

```
<div class = "container" v-show = "work">
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <div class = "todoArea" id = "todoEl">
      <p> Finish All Tasks To Start A New Session : </p>
      <ul class = "collection">
            <li v-for="task in tasks" v-bind:class="{done: task.checked} collection-item">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" v-model="task.checked">
                <label for="checkbox">{{{ task.text }}</label>
           </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `div` shows up but the `ul` is empty, there are no `li`, however when open the console and type the following :

```
JSON.parse(localStorage["pr_sessions"]) // This print an array in the console
```

And this too:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage["pr_sessions"])[JSON.parse(localStorage["pr_currSession"]) - 1].tasks
```

It shows me the tasks of that current session correctly, I don't have any error in my console, neither my background console .

The problem is that there are no tasks shown in the div, why ?

**Possible Reason for this :** There is one possible reason for this to not work, is that at first before the app state turns to `work`, it doesn't have `localStorage["pr_currSession"]` , But once the state is `work` it exist .
Could this be the reason why it's not showing any tasks ?

Comment: hmmm, what does vue-devtool says about your `tasks` object?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, at the time of initialisation of vue instance, there are no tasks saved in localStorage, but they are there later on.

I don't see code to populate tasks variable when localStorage has tasks. as you are saying: once the state is work tasks exist

You can put [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on state variable, and load the tasks, when this changes.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your template has some errors:

- Use `v-bind:class="{done: task.checked}" class="collection-item"`
  Instead of `v-bind:class="{done: task.checked} collection-item"`
- Remove the extra bracket from `{{{ task.text }}`

You could use the uncompressed version (not the `min.js`) during development, to get cool warnings!